# Full Calendar - Error Loading JSON events

Tags: php, ajax, fullcalendar

I am having trouble with Full Calendar (FC) to read the JSON object I have returned from my database to display events on the calendar. Where could I be overlooking?

My jQuery for FC is here:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',
        titleFormat: "MMMM YYYY",
        header: {
            left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
        },
        events: {
            url: "../ajax/tutor/json_events.php",
            type: "POST",
            color: "yellow",
            textColor: "black",
            error: function() {
                alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
            }
        }
    });
```

The `json_events.php` is here:

```
$returnArray = array();
$userID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id");

$connect = db();

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM Lessons WHERE TutorID = 1");

if($stmt->execute()){
    $results = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowArray['start'] = $row['Start'];
        $rowArray['end'] = $row['End'];
        $rowArray['title'] = $row['CourseTaught'];

        array_push($returnArray, $rowArray);
    }

    $json = json_encode($returnArray);
}

echo print_r($json);

$stmt->close();
```

The JSON object displays perfectly, however the alert is being thrown from jquery events for some reason, I am just overlooking the error somehow. A fresh pair of eyes would be useful.

Comment: Just use `echo $json;` .... ___Loose the `print_r()`___

Comment: Hello is your json valid??? Kindly post json response in question..

Comment: This is what is returned http://adonnelly759.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/mii/ajax/tutor/json_events.php

Comment: Right now that link of yours returns nothing at all. But Riggs is right, just `echo $json;` is correct. Now presumably you need to check whether `$json` actually contains anything. Perhaps your statement failed to execute? Or perhaps there were no results? You aren't checking for the success of your statement preparation or execution. Also, if that's the whole of your json_events.php, then where is `db();` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add square brackets around `$json`, something like `echo('['.$json.']');`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a human-readable dump of the variable in PHP by using [print_r()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Your JavaScript is expecting the true JSON object without formatting.

Simply `echo $json;` instead of `echo print_r($json);` and you will get your json object without the surrounding `<pre>` tags.